# How to solve this matrix equation

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

How to solve the following matrix equation?

```
Solve[MatrixRank[{{1, x, 3},
                  {2, 4, 5},
                  {2, 4, x}}] == 2, x, Reals]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations)

Comment: By the way, variants of this question have appeared [hither](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/compute-the-rank-of-a-matrix-with-variable-entries), [thither](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97093/how-write-a-new-matrixrank-feature-with-symbolic-computation), and [yon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165165/solving-linear-systems-with-parameters). That yon actually has a more general approach in a comment: it can be used for non-square matrices as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A not so good answer

```
Cases[Table[{x, MatrixRank[({{1, x, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, x}})]}, {x, -10, 10, 1/10}], {_, 2}]
```

gives out

> {{2, 2}, {5, 2}}

So the answer is 2 or 5.

Answer (score 19):

```
mat = ({{1, x, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, x}});
Select[MatrixRank[mat /. #] == 2 &][Solve[Det[mat] == 0, x, Reals]]
```

> {{x -> 2}, {x -> 5}}

Answer (score 14):

Solutions force exactly one eigenvalue to be zero. So we solve for the condition that an eigenvalue vanish, and check that rank is two.

```
mat = {{1, x, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, x}};
candidateSols = Flatten[Map[Solve[# == 0, x] &, Eigenvalues[(mat)]]]

(* Out[997]= {x -> 2, x -> 5} *)
```

Both pass the test:

```
Map[MatrixRank[mat /. #] &, candidateSols]

(* Out[995]= {2, 2} *)
```

Comment: I should have read the @kglr answer more carefully. It avoids, or at least postpones, working in an algebraic extension.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an indirect route, which has the advantage of postponing operations like `MatrixRank[]` until the end.

Consider the identity

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&x&3\\2&4&5\\2&4&x\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&3\\2&4&5\\2&4&0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}x&0\\0&0\\0&x\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

A condition for this matrix to be invertible (cf. the [Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)) is that the *capacitance matrix*

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&3\\2&4&5\\2&4&0\end{pmatrix}^{(-1)}\begin{pmatrix}x&0\\0&0\\0&x\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1-\frac{x}{2}&-\frac{x}{20}\\0&1-\frac{x}{5}\end{pmatrix}$$

be nonsingular.

Thus,

```
Solve[Det[IdentityMatrix[2] +
          {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}.LinearSolve[{{1, 0, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 0}},
                                             {{x, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, x}}]] == 0, x]
   {{x -> 2}, {x -> 5}}
```

Check:

```
MatrixRank /@ ({{1, x, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, x}} /. %)
   {2, 2}
```

Comment: A great answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a `MatrixRankSym` feature with symbolic computation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262568/21532). And we can use for this question directly:

```
Solve[MatrixRankSym[{{1, x, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, x}}] == 2, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 2}, {x -> 5}}

Answer (score 0):

You get rank == 2, if one row is the linear combination of the two others.

```
mat= {{1, x, 3}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, x}};

Solve[aa mat[[1]] + bb mat[[2]] == mat[[3]], {x, aa, bb}, Reals]

(*  {{x -> 2, aa -> -6, bb -> 4}, {x -> 5, aa -> 0, bb -> 1}}    *)
```